# Philippine passport transit in UK, need help

Tags: uk, transit, international-travel, airport-transfer, filipino-citizens

Im a filipino with a tourist visa in canada, I have a flight from Doha to London LHR then London Gatwick airport to Vancouver, Do i need a transit visa knowing that Im transfering airport in UK. Thanks advance your replies